# Android Null object reference on parsing color

Tags: java, android, colors

Im trying to parse a color from a text file but it errors and crashes.

I am getting the error in logcat when running the code:

```
   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'char java.lang.String.charAt(int)' on a null object reference
```

The colors are being retrieved from a text file where the color strings are stored:

```
#01DF01
#FF0000
```

Snippet of color Code:

```
  private void fillView2(View view, String dataset4Value, String dataset5Value, String dataset6Value) {
        TextView textView1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        TextView textView2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        TextView textView3 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView3);

        textView1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(dataset4Value));
        textView2.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(dataset5Value));
        textView3.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(dataset6Value));
    }
```

Other code:

```
 int maxDataSetSize = Math.max(data1.size(), Math.max(data2.size(), data3.size())) ;

        for (int i = 0; i < maxDataSetSize; i++) {
            String dataset1Value = data1.size() > i ? data1.get(i) : null;
            String dataset2Value = data2.size() > i ? data2.get(i) : null;
            String dataset3Value = data3.size() > i ? data3.get(i) : null;

            View statsRowview = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.stats_row, null);

            fillView(statsRowview, dataset1Value, dataset2Value, dataset3Value);

            tableStats.addView(statsRowview);
        }
```

Comment: Post relevant code where you are using `charAt` ??

Comment: That method requires 3 strings, but you've only listed 2, could that be the issue?

Comment: Nope, its getting strings from different files. Ill post my whole code to make it more understandable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ternary operators are setting your Strings to null in some cases:

```
String dataset1Value = data1.size() > i ? data1.get(i) : null;
```

So "fillView" is receiving "null" strings that will cause the exception when "charAt" is invoked.

Replacing "null" by empty string might not fix the problem depending on your "fillView" implementation, as you may get an OutOfBounds exception.

I think the best option (without having a look into fillView method) is to replace "null" by a default color string. For instance:

```
final static String DEFAULT_COLOR = "#FFFFFF"; // White color by default.

...
String dataset1Value = data1.size() > i ? data1.get(i) : DEFAULT_COLOR;
String dataset2Value = data2.size() > i ? data2.get(i) : DEFAULT_COLOR;
String dataset3Value = data3.size() > i ? data3.get(i) : DEFAULT_COLOR;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem should be here:

```
for (int i = 0; i < maxDataSetSize; i++) {
            String dataset1Value = data1.size() > i ? data1.get(i) : null;
            String dataset2Value = data2.size() > i ? data2.get(i) : null;
            String dataset3Value = data3.size() > i ? data3.get(i) : null;

            View statsRowview = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.stats_row, null);

            fillView(statsRowview, dataset1Value, dataset2Value, dataset3Value);

            tableStats.addView(statsRowview);
        }
```

You are probably passing null strings to your method. Maybe initialize them as empty Strings "" or check in your method if they are null first before calling parseColor. (not sure about how parseColor works)

Comment: This works fine as before i added it to parse colors the value was showing up, i believe its the color causing issue and likewise i dont know how it works.